# Hide or remove value from list if selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list, and I want to remove the list option if it is selected.

**For Example**:

If the user selects one of the list options, I want to remove the option from the list as it will be seen as the selected value. Can I achieve this by using either jquery or CSS? Can anyone help me?

It is getting removed

but the issue is suppose the user selects "A", the value "A" from the list is removed but again when the user selects "B", how do I add the value "A" back into the list

Below is my html file:

```html
<dl id='assettypes' class="dropdown">
  <dt>
  <a href="#">
     <span>
        Select option
     </span>                                              
   </a>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <ul id="ggg">
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I know how to achieve this using select and options but not sure how to do it with ul, li

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to attach a click event handler to each of the **[`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)** elements. From there, you can simply make use of **[`$(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** to target the element that is clicked on, and **[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)** to hide it:

```js
$('#ggg > li').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dl id='assettypes' class="dropdown">
  <dt>
  <a href="#">
     <span>
        Select option
     </span>                                              
   </a>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <ul id="ggg">
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: And a `.addClass("selected")` ? *-- «remove it from the list as it will anyhow be seen as the selected value.»*

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - Sure, you could add a class to denote that an option is selected as it gets hidden (not removed from the DOM), and then go on to check which options are hidden for some sort of calculation later. However, by the "*selected value*" I *assume* the OP means more along the lines of "*they're clicking this item, so therefor this is the item they want to target*". In that sort of an instance, you could do whatever you need to with the element in question with a simple `$(this)` :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge  It is getting removed but the issue is suppose the user selects "A", the value "A" from the list is removed but again when the user selects "B", how do I add the value "A" back into the list?